# How can I split a string and take only one from the separated string in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string which includes ":", it shows like this:

```
: SHOES
```

and I want to split the colon and SHOES, then make a variable that contains only "SHOES"

I have split them used df.split(':') but then how should I create a variable with "SHOES" only?

Comment: Are you trying to apply this on pandas dataframe or simple string? You tagged `pandas` it makes confusing so

Answer (score 2):

You can use the list slicing function. and then use lstrip and rstrip to remove excess spaces before and after the word.

```
df=": shoes"
d=df.split(":")[-1].lstrip().rstrip()
print(d)
```

Comment: Use [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) if you want to remove characters from both side. - `df.split(":")[-1].strip()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'apply' method to execute a loop over all dataset and split the column with 'split()'.

This is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[':abd', ':cda', ':vfe', ':brg']})

    # First we create a new column just named a new column -> df['new_column']
    # Second, we loop dataset with apply
    # Third, we execute a lambda with split function, getting only text after ':'
df['new_column']=df['A'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[1] )

df
        A   new_column
0   :abd    abd
1   :cda    cda
2   :vfe    vfe
3   :brg    brg
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small working sample. Both `stripValue` and `newString` `return` the same `value`. It is matter cleaner code vs verbose code:

```
    # set initial string
    myString = "string : value"
    
    # split it which will return an array [0,1,2,3...]
    stripValue = myString.split(":")

    # you can create a new var with the value you want/need from the array
    newString = (stripValue[1])
    
    # or you can short hand it
    print(stripValue[1])
    
    # calling the new var
    print(newString)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your original strings always start with ": " then you could just remove the first two characters using:

```
myString[2:]
```